# is there any difference between those AJAX methods?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have two questions about jQuery AJAX.

1) Is there any difference between `$.load()` and `$.ajax() used with type: 'GET'`? They seem to do the same job.

2) This question is related to the code below. What happens, if I don't write the "type: GET" line at all? Does it mean the same thing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#update').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'hello-ajax.html',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(html, textStatus) {
      $('body').append(html);
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('An error occurred! ' + ( errorThrown ? errorThrown :
      391
      xhr.status );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Is it any different from

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#update').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'hello-ajax.html',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(html, textStatus) {
      $('body').append(html);
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('An error occurred! ' + ( errorThrown ? errorThrown :
      391
      xhr.status );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: LOL! 2 books about an AJAX call? I wonder what they found to say about it to write a whole book about that!

Comment: load does [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/), ajax does [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Did you miss the part in the manual where it explains the difference?

Comment: As for the second question, again the manual tells you that GET is the default type.

Comment: @HasanAlaca: Well, I 'm not sure why it took 2 books when the answer is really 2 sentences. The docs for `load` begin with "This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function.", and those for `$.get` begin with "This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to: `$.ajax(...)`". Is there something this does not explain? You literally have to read **the first line of the docs**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straight from jQuery Docs (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

Since `$.get()` is simply the `$.ajax()` shorthand for "data: 'Get'", it would appear the only major difference is the ability to do the aforementioned (import partial sections of a document).

Edit:  To answer your second question, GET is the default data type for the $.ajax() call, POST being your other option.  You can read a bit about POST here (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: @HasanAlaca happy to help!  Don't forget to check the most appropriate answer as correct!

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from jQuery manual [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus
>   is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data. This means that most uses of the
>   method can be quite simple:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

> If no element is matched by the selector — in this case, if the
>   document does not contain an element with id="result" — the Ajax
>   request will not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the difference is that .load() function allows to target the result into a DOM element. Like so

```
$( "#target" ).load( "source.html" );
```

And the ajax() method returns an object (eg. JSON) that can be the manipulated. etc. apart from more attributes.